# Why does this specific Offset function return a value error when combined with Sumproduct?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to write a formula that will multiply the values in every 3rd column by 3. I tried to achieve this with a Sumproduct function with an internal Offset function as a counter.

Why does the Offset function ONLY return a Value Error when it's below the range of data it's supposed to offset? See the image below, the function correctly returns the value '3' when it is adjacent to the range of data, but returns an error when the function is pasted below the data.

Furthermore, although the Offset function correctly returns a value when written adjacent to the data range, why does combining the function with a Sumproduct still return an error?

[image: Screenshot of relevant Excel Worksheet]

Comment: Working fine for me. Must be something in your file. What do you see in the Evaluate formula box in the step before the #VALUE! shows?

Comment: Didn't work for me on SCALC.exe  but this did =SUMPRODUCT((OFFSET($L$4:$U22,COLUMN(A2)*3,3)))  removing 0,

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of Excel, all of these formulas will work, because at this point, `OFFSET` can return dynamic arrays.

It seems you are using an earlier version of Excel. I was able to simulate the behavior you're seeing by using the '@' operator.

This call to `OFFSET` returns the `#VALUE!` error whenever you refer to a range that does not include the row where you are entering the formula. So, you get the #VALUE! error both above and below the range you're trying to calculate from:

[image]

You'll find also that for your formulas to the left or right, if you drag them both up and down, they start to display the error as soon as the formula goes above or below the row limits of the reference inside the function:

[image]

I suppose in earlier versions of Excel, they were trying to avoid returning arrays into ranges that might overlap with other data either above or below. So the element of the array you return is always in the same row as the reference range/array.

As for the `SUMPRODUCT` issue, it returns zero because the OFFSET is creating an error, which is treated as a zero.

Regardless of that, array dimensions must be the same, so even if OFFSET was not returning an error here, SUMPRODUCT would because you have a single value in the second parameter.

Generally, I think if you do not have dynamic array support in your version of Excel, you should try to come up with an approach that doesn't use offset in this way. If you edit your post to include more details regarding your intended outcome and purpose, I can try to help.

Answer (score 0):

`OFFSET` does not seem to produce an array `SUMPRODUCT` can use. It does when one internally calculates formula arts with `F9`, but... not when Excel does it in whatever manner it does it.

However, `OFFSET` IS producing an array internally, as one can see with `F9`. All one needs to do is force ("coerce") Excel to use it.

Wrapping it with `INDEX` (as in `INDEX(OFFSET(...),,1)` to capture all rows) keeps Excel from losing `OFFSET`'s array.

Then, of course, as `FlexYourData` points out, one must match array structures so a simple `SEQUENCE(ROWS($I$4:$I$22),1,3,0)` rounds out the formula.

If using an older version, one builds the last array differently, but easily enough. So for an older version, the only real question is whether `SUMPRODUCT` will use these pieces. Structurally, there's no problem, as it is properly formed for plain "Enter" entry, but one always has "Control-Shift-Enter" ("{CSE}")if not. Just the question of whether it takes the arrays or cuts them at one value each (=9). But functions like `SUMPRODUCT` were written specifically with this in mind so I believe it should work fine.

(Of course, it looks like you want a column of 19 entries, so selecting the cells and using "{CSE}" entry would seem indicated.)